# SQL Увеличить datetime на 1 день

Tags: mysql, sql, дата, datetime, update

Как я могу увеличить datetime на 1 день, в строках где daily=1?

Моя неудачная попытка:

```
UPDATE shows SET datetime_start = DATE(DATE_ADD(datetime_start, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) = CURRENT_DATE WHERE daily = 1
```

Comment: `UPDATE shows SET datetime_start = datetime_start + INTERVAL 1 DAY WHERE daily = 1;`

Comment: Спасибо, если не сложно сделайте полноценный ответ (я отмечу его как правильным)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE shows 
SET datetime_start = datetime_start + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
WHERE daily = 1;
```